# Syntax Error In Oracle Function

Tags: oracle, stored-functions

I'm trying to make a function that does a simple `insert` into a table called `poli`, the purpose of this fuction:

- returns 1 when it inserts the values to the table
- in any other case it    returns 0.

This is the code in oracle that i wrote:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADDPOLI 
( ID IN NUMBER, NAME IN VARCHAR2 , LON IN FLOAT , LAT IN FLOAT , STATUS OUT NUMBER ) 
return status

          IS cursor poli_count is select count(id) from poli;

BEGIN

    declare number_of_cities int;

    fetch poli_c into number_of_cities;
if number_of_cities<= 15 and number_of_cities>=0 then
insert into poli values(id,name,lat,lon);
return 1;
else 
return 0;
end if;

END ADDPOLI;
```

> i have a syntax error here: fetch poli_c into number_of_cities;

how can i fix it ?

Comment: Is your database MySQL or Oracle? I see you have VARCHAR2 and NUMBER which are Oracle data types, not recognized by MySQL. But your subject and tag says mysql.

Comment: its oracle, im sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are using cursor to achieve this. Try below -

```
CREATE FUNCTION ADDPOLI(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(255), LON FLOAT, LAT FLOAT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

declare number_of_cities int;

select count(id) into number_of_cities from poli;
if number_of_cities between 0 and 15 then
    insert into poli values(id,name,lat,lon);
    return 1;
else 
    return 0;
end if;
END
```

Comment: @phill Try now.

Comment: I'll also fix the data types.

Comment: I'm sorry to have spent the time editing your answer and testing it on MySQL. The OP is using Oracle.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new with databases , i'm very sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 1):

There is something more fundamentally of concern here.  What happens when you deploy this function in a multi-user environment (which most databases typically will run in).

The logic of:

"Do I have less than 15 cities?"
"Yes, insert another row"

is more complex than first appears.  Because if I have 10 sessions all currently running this function, you can end up with the following scenario:

I start with say 13 rows.  Then this happens:

- Session 1: Is there less than 15? Yes, do the insert.
- Session 2: Is there less than 15? Yes, do the insert.
- Session 3: Is there less than 15? Yes, do the insert.
- Session 4: Is there less than 15? Yes, do the insert.
- Session 5: Is there less than 15? Yes, do the insert.
- ...

and *now* Session 1 commits, and so forth for Session 2, 3, ....

And hence voila!  You now have 18 rows in your table and everyone is befuddled as to how this happened.

Ultimately, what you are after is a means of enforcing a rule about the data ("max of 15 rows in table X").  There is a lengthy discussion about the complexities of doing that over at AskTOM

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=declarative-integrity

Comment: didn't know that was actually possible, what does a "session" represents? a connected user?or a "transaction"?

Comment: A session is a connection to the database.  That might be 1-to-1 with an actual user, but more likely, one of the members of a connection pool that "real users" are utilizing.  Obviously the time between the insertion and commit is typically small, but that simply lowers the probability of the corruption happening rather than eliminate it